# Can I define a nameless method in a Scala class?

Tags: class, scala, syntax, methods

Is this possible to reach? If yes, please correct my Foo declaration syntax.

```
class Foo (...) {
...
  def /* the nameless method name implied here */ (...) : Bar = new Bar (...)
...
}

class Bar (...) {
...
}

val foo : Foo = new Foo (...)

val fooBar : Bar = foo (...)
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You should use the apply method:

```
class Foo (y: Int) {
  def apply(x: Int) : Int = x + y
}


val foo : Foo = new Foo (7)

val fooBar  = foo (5)

println(fooBar)
```

Then run the code:

```
bash$ scala foo.scala 
12
```

Answer (score 4):

I think the using 'apply' for you method name should work like this.

Answer (score 4):

You can extend `Function0[Bar]` and implement `def apply: Bar`. See [`Function0`](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/Function0.html):

```
 object Main extends Application {
   val currentSeconds = () => System.currentTimeMillis() / 1000L
   val anonfun0 = new Function0[Long] {
     def apply(): Long = System.currentTimeMillis() / 1000L
   }
   println(currentSeconds())
   println(anonfun0())
 }
```

Comment: Just to clarify, there are two definitions shown here.  `currentSeconds` here is an *anonymous function*, and is basically syntactic sugar for the definition shown by `anonfun0`